# Create cron job to run with MySQL

Tags: cron

I've got a code that will delete a WordPress post from my database if it contains a certain text:

```
DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE post_excerpt LIKE "%neuroscience%"
```

I want to get this to run every hour, but I don't know if I should initiate this within the MySQL platform, or via cPanel. I would prefer the latter so all my cron jobs would be in one place. But the truth is I don't know how to code either!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just `CREATE TRIGGER` in MySQL itself ?
It will delete the post whenever they occur and if you use `BEFORE UPDATE` it won't even get into the database.

Comment: I'll give it a try.

What, if anything, do I put in the definer?

I've run the query manually, and now I should expect it to take over from here?

Comment: I think I have another issue, my code doesn't seem to work if manually executed from MySQL directly. I used a WP plugin called SQL Execute which works.

Is my code correct? 

DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE post_content LIKE "%[unable to data]%"

Comment: The `CREATE TRIGGER` needs some clause to make it run like `AFTER UPDATE` or `BEFORE INSERT`.